# Sharing cookies between domain and a subdomain using IIS express

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, cookies, jwt

I'm trying to share a cookie between two ASP.NET mvc 6 apps :

- The first one is a web api app and it should represent the main domain "localhost".
- Second one is an empty mvc website client app, with one index.html that calls the web api via simple ajax. this app represents the subdomain "cleint.lohalhost".

For somereason, my browser is unable to set the cookie on the client app. Details below :

-Set cookie header generated by web api

```
Set-Cookie:mytoken=mytokenvalue; domain=.localhost; path=/; samesite=lax
```

-Ajax call :

```
$.get({
    url: 'http://localhost:5004/api/values',
    success: function (response) { console.log(response); },
    error: function (error) { console.log(error); },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
});
```

-And finally, the code that sets the cookie on the web api app :

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    Response.Cookies.Append("mytoken", "mytokenvalue", new CookieOptions() { Domain = ".localhost" });
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

-I use chrome browser if it's relevant.

I appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

Comment: I guess it's possible Chrome isn't passing the .localhost:5004 API cookie to your localhost:80 (presumably) MVC app, though AFAIK port numbers should not be considered as part of a cookie's domain. Does your API cookie exist on subsequent requests to your API, i.e. have you verified it's actually being set at all?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, Yes the cookie was not being set at all, the solution I was able to able to find is detailed below. it's also not related to Chrome since I've managed to reproduce the error on Edge browser as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my browser was still hungry for another '.' on the domain name, so I ended up replacing 'localhost' (on both domain names) with 'myapp.dev' and it worked.
It is also important to note that from the api side, I had to send the domain name cookie option with the value '.myapp.dev' instead of 'client.myapp.dev'